# Interfaces with stampit 2

Tags: javascript, interface, ecmascript-6, composition, stampit.js

As mentioned in the [interface section](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000262/ch04.html#interfaces) of '**Programming javascript applications**' you can implement interfaces with [stampit](https://github.com/stampit-org/stampit). When reducing the unnecessary stuff from the example, I end up with something like this:

```
const fooBarInterface = 
    stampit()
        .methods(
            {
                foo: () => {
                    throw new Error('connect not implemented'); 
            },
                bar: () => {
                    throw new Error('save not implemented');
            }
        }
    )
```

Excerpt from an interface definition:

> If your class claims to implement an interface, all methods defined by
>   that interface must appear in its source code before the class will
>   successfully compile.

So now putting the interface in use

```
const fooBarImplementation = 
    stampit()
        .compose(fooBarInterface)
        .methods(
            {
                foo: () => {
                    // implement me
                }
            }
        }
    )
```

Now, when composing an object from the stamp, there should be an error because bar is not implemented by fooBarImplementation. It isn't, and I fear that it's pretty hard to get something like this in place because there is no compiling at all.

So, my question is: Am I doing it wrong or is this half baked thing what Eric Elliott calls an 'Interface'?

Comment: I just wrote a small stamp that checks the methods for implementation:

https://github.com/mdix/interface-check-stamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [module](http://github.com/mdix/interface-check-stamp) you've created is great! You really know stampit well.

Although, in JavaScript I would recommend to go a different path. Namely, check if method is present.

```
if (obj.bar) kangaroo.bar();
```

And remove the `fooBarInterface` entirely. But if you need to check the method presence while creating the object, then you should do it similar to your module.

```
var ValidateFooBar = stampit()
  .init(function() {
    if (!_.isFunction(this.foo)) throw new Error('foo not implemented');
    if (!_.isFunction(this.bar)) throw new Error('bar not implemented');
  });
```

And use it:

```
const fooBarImplementation = stampit()
  .compose(ValidateFooBar)
  .methods({
    foo: function() {
      // implement me
    }
  });
```

Will throw: `Error: bar not implemented`